# Why does Firefox ask me to allow Flash twice?

Tags: firefox, flash

After one of the recent updates, Firefox is prompting me twice to allow Flash to run in any website which has Flash. I will show an example from Google Voice, but this happens on practically every website with Flash.

I first get this prompt:

[image]

If I allow, then I get this prompt:

[image]

Where are these prompts coming from? Why am I being asked twice? How can I remove both of these, and delegate the decision of allowing Flash to NoScript?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/715907/155919

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable message bar asking to allow a hidden plugin](http://superuser.com/questions/715811/disable-message-bar-asking-to-allow-a-hidden-plugin)